# System.IO - Use Directory/LINQ to Replace Some Files in a List with Others

Tags: linq, system.io.file, system.io.directory

I get a list of files using the System.IO Directory thusly:

```
var srcFiles = Directory.GetFiles(remotePath);
```

I also have a comma separated list of strings, each of which I want to check  for NON-existence in the names of the above files. For example:

```
string[] filterOn = EndPoint.FileNameDoesNotContainFilter.Split(',').ToArray();
```

gives me the following array:

```
filterOn contains ["GoodFile", "EvenBetterFile"]
```

Now, the files *without* either of the two strings would replace all the files currently in the srcFiles list above (or a new list, if that makes more sense). I am trying to do this with LINQ, but can't quite get there. How is it done?

EDIT: The answer from @dvo gives me the correct files, however, sometimes the filter strings are contained in the remotePath passed in.

A typical path/file: C:\TEMP\APPS\AMS\Services\sc0189v\APPS\GoodFile\test.txt.

As you can see, "GoodFile" is in the path, but not the filename. Yet this file should be rejected. I suppose I'm looking for something in System.IO.Directory that might help. Not sure, really.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var noMatch = srcFiles.Where(file => !filterOn.Any(filter => file.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(filter.ToUpperInvariant()))).ToList();
```

This will create a new list where the file name does not contain any filter. This ignores case by converting both the file name and filter to uppercase. You can store the results in the same list if you replace `noMatch` with `srcFiles`. You can make it case sensitive if you remove `.ToUpperInvariant()` from both parts of the `Any` clause. You can capture the filter matches by removing the `!` from the `Where` clause.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Suggest creating the `filterOn` array uppercased rather than uppercasing each element every test.

Comment: Yes. That did it. See my question though if you'd maybe like to help with a related issue.

Comment: How about `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.ToUpper())`? The whole line: `var noMatch = srcFiles.Where(file => !filterOn.Any(filter => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.ToUpperInvariant()).Contains(filter.ToUpperInvariant()))).ToList();`. Combine this with NetMage's suggestion and remove `ToUpperInvariant` from filter.